# Python BS4 Sort HTML in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, html, sorting, beautifulsoup

How to sort the html code to be in alphabetical order?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''[<div>Red </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Orange </div>, <div>Blue </div>]'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
paints = soup.findAll("div")

print(str(paints).strip('[]'))
```

Output:

```
<div>Red </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Orange </div>, <div>Blue </div>
```

Wanted Output:

```
<div>Blue </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Red </div>, <div>Orange </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `sorted` function in your code and use `key` for sorting as text from the tag using `get_text()` method and it will return data as per required.

```
sorted(paints, key=lambda x: x.get_text())
```

Output:

```
[<div>Blue </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Orange </div>, <div>Red </div>]
```

Comment: Indeed `sorted()` even better - not seeing the wood for the trees

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not alphabetical - Anyway try to iterate the alphabet and check if your elements text startswith the character.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string

html = '''[<div>Red </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Orange </div>, <div>Blue </div>]'''

sorted_html_tags =[]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
    for e in soup.find_all("div"):
        if e.text.lower().startswith(c):
            sorted_html_tags.append(e)

sorted_html_tags
```

##### Output

```
[<div>Blue </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Orange </div>, <div>Red </div>]
```